# how can I make windows sandbox use the hosts file

Tags: windows-10, windows-sandbox

I've noticed that the windows sandbox doesn't seem to listen to the hosts file directives.

I've opened C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file with notepad as administrator and try the first test line

```
   127.0.0.1     x.acme.com              # x client host
```

However when I do `ping x.acme.com` it doesn't respond.

For some reason hosts file is ignored.

Any ideas how to change this behavior?

Comment: Are you editing the hosts file within the sandbox or without, and do you start the sandbox before or after the edit and have you done an ipconfig /flushdns? And have you tested the same outside of the sandbox, to compare results?

Comment: I'm editing the hosts file inside the sandbox. Normal Windows hosts file works correctly but I want to have a different record in the sandbox to test a staging environment on a clean system.

Comment: Does it detect what you have in your own hostsfile though? I think it will only use your real hosts file, not the sandboxed one. If you want to differentiate, you may need to install a DNS server and run that inside the sandbox. Also, this does sound like a bug. ;) maybe inform Microsoft about this. The Sandbox is still being actively developed.

Comment: Indeed it's using the real hosts file and I would llike to differentiate :(

Comment: I have submitted it but I was hoping there might be a hidden setting for it or a registry key that I don't know about  which alters this behaviour.

Comment: @gabtzi - There isn’t

Comment: In my testing, Sandbox correctly uses its own `hosts` file inside the Sandbox (i.e. it uses the hosts inside the Sandbox and not the hosts on the Host system) and can correctly resolve hostnames to IP addresses. It all works normally and as expected.